# rails 4.2.0 with whenever gem in development env, not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, development-environment, whenever

Hi everyone I have such problem:

I'm using rails 4.2.0 with rvm gemsets (using right ruby version and correct gemset with installed gems).
I'm trying to make some cron task using whenever gem, but I can't make it work.

This is what I have:

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'whenever', :require => false
```

**Model**

```
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

**schedule.rb**

```
set :environment, :development

every 1.minute do
  runner "SomeModel.create"
end
```

after using

> whenever --update-crontab store

**my Crontab**

```
# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: /home/user/project/config/schedule.rb
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/user/project && bin/rails runner -e development '\''SomeModel.create'\'''

# End Whenever generated tasks for: /home/user/project/config/schedule.rb
```

In cron.log I see that task was executed, but I don't see any new objects in db(I'm using mysql).

So I try create new project with model. I use mysql-lite and add whenever gem with same type of task. Then I updated crontab and whenever start to work fine, until I use mysql instead mysql-lite.

I don't find any troubleshooting using mysql and whenever in whenever docs, so I stuck with this (using console I can create object without problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using output in schedule help me to find a problem.

I used specific gemset and not specify it in my schedule.
That's why I got error. Whenever gem trying to use default gemset which was different from gemset that I use for my project.

So there are two options for solving problem, use default gemset or specify yours in schedule.

**Sample of setting gemset and env:**

> set :environment, :development

*Rake:*

> job_type :rake,  "cd :path && $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm && rvm use
>   2.2.0@somename && rake ':task' :output"

*Runner:*

> job_type :runner, "cd :path && $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm && rvm use 2.2.0@somename && bin/rails runner ':task' :output"